# .htaccess multiple extensions redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Question is very simple.
Is there any way so I can change my htaccess file from:
`RewriteRule ^up/(.*).zip$ upload/file.php?id=$1.zip [NC]
RewriteRule ^up/(.*).rar$ upload/file.php?id=$1.rar [NC]
RewriteRule ^up/(.*).7z$ upload/file.php?id=$1.7z [NC]
RewriteRule ^up/(.*).dmg$ upload/file.php?id=$1.dmg [NC]`
To something like: (i know its not correct but its idea)
`Extensions = [zip,rar,7z,dmg]
foreach(extensions as ext)
RewriteRule ^up/(.*).ext$ upload/file.php?id=$1.ext [NC]`

Or it isn't possible?
I just don't want to have TONS of lines for every extension...

Comment: I manged to add something like that: ________________________________________________ 
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^\.(exe|zip)`
______________________________________ 
`RewriteRule ^up/(.*)$ upload/file.php?id=$1 [NC]` 
But is that correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a  single pattern :

```
RewriteRule ^up/(.+).(zip|rar|7z|dmg)$ upload/file.php?id=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, however i still need to learn more about all this (.+) (.*) and stuff cuz i have no fckin idea what that means haha ;p